# Function expansion to minterms(SOP) and maxterms(POS) without using truth table

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

This is the function: $f(A,B,C,D) = (A' + C)' + D'$, and I also can't use one term's complement to find the other term.

What I did for minterms is:

$(A\cdot B'\cdot C' \cdot D')+(A' \cdot B' \cdot C' \cdot D')+(A' \cdot B' \cdot C' \cdot D') = (A\cdot B'\cdot C' \cdot D')+(A' \cdot B' \cdot C' \cdot D') = m_0m_8$,

but i think it's wrong. Also, I don't get what i have to do for maxterms.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: With $AC'$ you get 4 minterms : $AxC'x$

Comment: With $D'$ you get 8 minterms: $xxxD'$

Comment: There will be 2 terms common to both: $AxC'D'$

Comment: So there will be $4+8-2 = 10$ minterms for the given function. How did you get just two minterms?

Comment: I thought I had to add the missing terms, then simplify, then match the products to the respective minterm.